# Using Moq For Stateful and Stateless Testing

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

aQuestion of Implementation.

I have a Builder Method FooBuilder() that calls many things to build up a model of FooModel.

The FooBuilder() has certain methods that depend on one another,such as Tire(barBuilder) calling BarBuilder, and many that don't, like SteeringWheel, that are independent of any execution ordering.

Example:

```
 [Test]
        public void then_should_build_steering_wheel_model()
        {
            // Arrange
            var FooBuilder = new FooBuilder();   
            var itemKey = new ItemKey{Vendor = 10};

            //Here's the setup of BarBuilder for other classes elsewhere
            var BarBuilder = new Mock<IBarBuilder>();
             BarBuilder.Setup(builder =>  builder.BuildUpBarMaster(itemKey.Vendor)).Returns(BarModel);


            // Act
            FooBuilder.CreateSteeringWheelModel(itemKey.vendor);

            // Assert
            FooBuilder.Verify(builder => builder.BuildUpSteeringWheelModel(itemKey.vendor));
```

Is there any way to build tests for a piece of the method that are stateless (SteeringWheel) without doing the setup for the stateful parts(BarBuilder)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this to make BarBuilder not return an instance of a model of BarBuilder, but rather a primitive type that needed to be passed down the line.

The primitives allows Moq to successfully ignore the errors about null method dependencies  about null objects that I was receiving.  Moq will then pass in 0's instead and run the program as intended leaving me to only use .Setup for things on which I **actually** need to.